# Are imports in Dart not recursive?

Tags: dart, import

I have a project file which includes `class MyFileStream extends Stream<someList>`. The file begins with `import 'dart:io';`.

When I try to implement the function `.listen()` inside `class MyFileStream` I found out that I needed to `import 'dart:async';` as well in the same file.

The thing is, `dart:async` is already imported in file *"/dart-sdk/lib/io/io.dart"* following the line `library dart.io;`.

So, why would I import `async` while it is already imported in `io`? This seems to be different than C language. Are imports private in Dart language? What is the idea behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If A imports B, and B imports C, the public symbols of C are visible in B, but *not* re-exported to A.  To do that, B would have to say `export 'C.dart';` instead of just `import 'C.dart';`

So, to answer your question, imports are *not* recursive by default, but they can be, on request.  This can be quite powerful, to also re-export a subset of a consumed interface using the proper show and hide operations.

An example of that is how flutter_riverpod completely re-publishes the riverpod classes:

```
export 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';
```

and how Riverpod carefully exports a portion of its internal symbols in https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/packages/riverpod/lib/riverpod.dart.